# UIAlertController - Override ActionSheet by default?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

I'm using a UIAlertController in my iOS app; however, for the sake of saving myself a duplicate line of code, I want to initialize the UIAlertController prior to an if/else branch. i.e.

```
var alertController = UIAlertController()

if /* something */ {
    alert.title = "Hello!"
} else {
    alert.title = "Goodbye!"
}

//yada yada actions yada yada

self.presentViewController(alert)
```

However, while I've found I can easily set the title and message after the fact, I can't seem to find a way to set the style. By default it seems to use an ActionSheet, but I really want an alert. I tried changing the`preferredStyle` property, but it seems to be read-only. Is there any way to change the style? For what it's worth, I'm on the latest iOS 8 SDK and using Swift.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `preferredStyle` can only be set at initialization.

You can try something like this:

```
var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

if /* something */ {
    alert.title = "Hello!"
} else {
    alert.title = "Goodbye!"
}

//yada yada actions yada yada

self.presentViewController(alert)
```